# RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked. Please read the readme, setup and troubleshooting instructions carefully Expo+ Firebase JS SDK

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-signin

I've issue with Expo. I'm using RN google signin  to implement google signin across platforms **along with Firebase JS-sdk**

**error** on web

> Uncaught Error: RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly
> linked. Please read the readme, setup and troubleshooting instructions
> carefully.  If you are using Expo, make sure you are using Custom dev
> client, not Expo go

**the error occurred once I use googole signin button**
like that
SignUpScreen.tsx

```
import {GoogleSignin,GoogleSigninButton} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

//...
<GoogleSigninButton
            size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
            color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Light}
           // onPress={}
            //disabled={}
            style={{ width:'100%', height:SIZES.xxSmall}}
          />
```

**app.json:**

```
"ios": {
      "config": {
        "usesNonExemptEncryption": false
      },

      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "bundleIdentifier",

    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },

      "package": "my package"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "favicon": "./src/assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "experiments": {
      "tsconfigPaths": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "projectId"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      
      "expo-font",
      **"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin"**
    ],
    "owner": "owner"
```

metro.config.ts

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
  const { transformer, resolver } = config;
  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
  };
  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext:any) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg",'cjs','mjs','d.ts',
  ]
  };
  
  
  return config;
})();
```

**package.json :**

```
dependencies:{
    "firebase": "^10.7.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^11.0.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
     "expo": "^50.0.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.8.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.5",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-native": "^0.73.2",}
```

GoogleLogin.tsx

```
import React,{useEffect ,useState} from 'react'
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import { makeRedirectUri } from 'expo-auth-session';
import app,{ auth,provider } from '../../../firebaseConfig';
import { 
  GoogleSignin,
  statusCodes,
  GoogleSigninButton,} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
 import {Web_Client_ID  } from "../../utils/clientKeys";


const GoogleLogin =() => {

 
 
  const googleSigninConfig = ():void =>{
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId:Web_Client_ID , 
      scopes: ["profile", "email"],
      offlineAccess: true, 
      forceCodeForRefreshToken: true, 
      profileImageSize: 120, 
    });
  }
  const onAuthStateChanged = (user:any)=> {
    if(user){
     console.log(user)
    }else{
      //set user info to null
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    googleSigninConfig()
    getCurrentUserInfo()
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged) 
      //triggered once user either log in or out 
    return subscriber;
  },[])


  const signinWithGoogle = async () => {//ongoogle btn press
    try {
        await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true });
       
        const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
        const {idToken, accessToken} = await GoogleSignin.getTokens()
        console.log(idToken,accessToken)
     
        const credential = 
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken,);
        await auth().signInWithCredential(credential); 
        
    }  catch (error :any) {
        if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
          console.log('SIGN_IN_CANCELLED')

        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
          console.log('IN_PROGRESS')

        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
          console.log('PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE')

        } else {
          // some other error happened
        }
    }
  }

   
  //return nyll if user didnt signin previously
  const getCurrentUserInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signInSilently()
      console.log(userInfo)
    } catch (error :any) {
        if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) {
          console.log('SIGN_IN_REQUIRED')
        } else {
          console.log('error')
           
        }
    }

  }
    
  const GoogleSignout = async ()=>{
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess()
      await GoogleSignin.signOut()
      //.then(() => alert('Your are signed out!'));
      // setloggedIn(false);
    } catch (error :any) {
           // Alert.alert('Something else went wrong... ', error.toString())
          }
  }
     
}
```

steps to achieve it
1_ Expo manged workflow

2_ development build   eas build --profile development --platform android

3_ npx expo install @react-native-google-signin/google-signin

4_ expo doctor Didn't find any issues with the project

5_ npx expo prebuild --clean

6_  npx expo start --dev-client

**on android** emulator stuck in splash screen with no issues 'Android Bundling complete'.

on web give the error above

github docs say follow readme instructions ,but nothing different than my setup.
this readme file
https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/blob/master/README.md
what have I done wrong ?? what is the cause of this error?
or is there any setup missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those came across a similar issue,
it was just related to firebase setup for web platform

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import { initializeApp, } from "firebase/app";

import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { getFirestore, enableIndexedDbPersistence } from "firebase/firestore";

// @ts-ignore 
import{initializeAuth, GoogleAuthProvider , inMemoryPersistence,
  getReactNativePersistence,setPersistence,}from 'firebase/auth';

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/functions';

let app: firebase.app.App;

 firebase.apps.length === 0 ?
 app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
:  app = firebase.app();
export const db = getFirestore(app);
const persistence = 
Platform.OS === 'web'                            //this line
            ?inMemoryPersistence as any         //this line
            :getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage);           
export const auth = initializeAuth(app, { persistence });
export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const database = getFirestore();
const storage = getStorage(app);
export {app}
```